# How is Stata implementing weights?

Tags: stata

Consider a very basic estimation command, `regress`. In the [manual](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/rregress.pdf), under Methods and Formulas, we read:

[image]

So, according to the manual, for `fweights`, Stata is taking my vector of weights (inputted with `fw=`), and creating a diagonal matrix `D`. Now, diagonal matrices have the same transpose. Therefore, we could define `D=C'C=C^2`, where `C` is a matrix containing the square root of my weights in the diagonal.

Now, given my notation and the text above, we can reproduce Stata's method by **premultiplying** both `X` and `y` (and `Z`) with the matrix `C`. This way, `(CX)'CX=X'C'CX=X'DX`, and so on. In practice we achieve this by multiplying each variable with the square root of the weight, observation by observation.

Now, I tried to replicate Stata's estimates manually, but I get a different result. Example code below:

```
webuse auto, clear

keep if !mi(rep78)
qui regress price weight length [fw=rep78]
estimates store stata
preserve
replace price = price*sqrt(rep78)
replace weight = weight*sqrt(rep78)
replace length = length*sqrt(rep78)

qui regress price weight length
estimates store me
restore
estimates table stata me, b
```

With output:

```
----------------------------------------
    Variable |   stata          me      
-------------+--------------------------
      weight |  4.1339379    1.7738167  
      length | -82.996394    16.502356  
       _cons |  9425.5443   -4071.7341  
----------------------------------------
```

The match is terrible. Results are the same if we change `fw=` with other forms of weights. Whats the issue? Is my math or code wrong? If not, how is Stata actually implementing the weights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This mismatch happens because you forgot to scale the intercept/constant:

```
webuse auto, clear
keep if !mi(rep78)
qui regress price weight length [fw=rep78]
estimates store stata
preserve
replace price = price*sqrt(rep78)
replace weight = weight*sqrt(rep78)
replace length = length*sqrt(rep78)
gen constant = 1*sqrt(rep78)
qui regress price weight length constant, nocons
estimates store me
restore
estimates table stata me, b
```

This replaces the usual column of ones with a "pseudo-intercept" that is the weighted version.

Comment: Evident my dear Watson! Thanks :) although notice there are decimal differences. Surely not enough to be statistically significant, but it is puzzling, because both methods should give, in principle, the exact same result.

Comment: Stata actually estimates the model in deviation form, so the numerical accuracy is going to be better when you avoid the multiplication method.

Comment: The difference is not too large unless the weights are negative.

Comment: Indeed. But as the mathematical method I used should be "exactly" the same as the formulas in the Stata doc, I thought I could reproduce the results.

Comment: This is done for reasons of numerical stability because you're working on a finite precision computer, akin to not actually calculating the inverse matrix in the OLS formula. The formula is the same one as in the manual.